How to Secure Ratchet Websocket connection with Laravel Passport
I have an Ionic app that will be sending location data back to a Laravel server via a Ratchet websocket.  The Ionic App uses Laravel Passport's client_credentials system for user authentication.  How can I verify that the user has been authenticated (i.e. using the Bearer token) as part of opening the websocket connection?
